# Giving milk and meat to a baby

Tags: halacha, minor-katan-child, meat-and-milk

We have a one-year-old, BH. Is it OK to give him milk and then meat and vice versa without waiting in between?

Comment: You got my downvote. While this site is great for _discussions_ of halacha, one should not use it for practical halachic questions, which should be directed to a competent authority. Your question is quite clearly a practical question applicable to you right now.

Comment: @msh please keep your moral judgements to yourself. what i do with the answers that i am given is my business

Comment: I apologize. I didn't mean to sound like I was passing judgement on you, and I wasn't. I meant only that the question is off-topic for the site: it's an administrative/"meta" comment about the question, rather than a moral comment about your actions.

Comment: It is perfectly fine to ask practical questions here in order to collect data, raise awareness, etc. (See the end of http://lo.yodeya.com/2010/01/more-from-linkedin-what-if-crowd-is.html). If, as in most cases, it's necessary to talk to your Rabbi to get a practical ruling for yourself, the sources and ideas brought up here (particularly for more obscure topics) can be helpful in the conversation with the Rabbi. All that said, *polite* reminders to "CYR" are perfectly appropriate in response to what look like attempts to get Pesak from the m.y crowd.

Comment: @msh no prob my friend have a great day

Comment: Move to Holland. The tradition here is to wait only 1 hour between eating meat and milk.

Comment: @BarryHammer How would that help them if they wanted to feed the child milk right away?

Answer (score 3):

Many Rabbanim I have heard say that starting from 1 wait an hour, from 2 - 2 hrs, and then increase it to the full six hours by 6 - however as usual Ask your local Orthodox Rabbi.

However between milk and meat unless it is the type of cheese that needs waiting, even adults just need to take a drink and a cracker or wash out the mouth, etc.

Comment: @gers adults need to wait an hour is what i heard most people do

Comment: Never heard an hour, heard of 1/2 hour according to some.

Comment: One hour is indeed a popular custom, based on the Zohar.

Comment: I would say "many" people wait an hour or a half-hour, both customs are not unheard-of. Plenty of good Jews don't, though.

Answer (score 1):

A good in depth treatment available [here](http://www.lakewood246.com/news/11463/can-children-eat-milk-after-meat.html).

Comment: Link is broken.  Found it on the internet archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20111013205643/http://www.lakewood246.com/news/11463/can-children-eat-milk-after-meat.html

Answer (score 1):

Baby - 3 (no need to wait)

3 - Age of Chinuch (wait 1 hour)

Age of Chinuch (wait according to family minhag)

Comment: Do you have a source for this recommendation (including "my grandmother said this is what we do"), or is this just your considered opinion?

Comment: I think it is in a sefer called children in halacha. I will b'n check for you once home

Comment: found a source?